# Why is "result := char variable" getting me access violation?

Tags: function, variables, delphi, get, char

I created a function that has a `Char` represented by a variable named `fsinal`:

```pascal
type
  TCalculo = class(TObject)
  private
    fnumero1 : integer;
    fnumero2 : integer;
    fsinal   : char;
  public
```

I then created a method to get this `Char`:

```pascal
function getSinal   : char;
    
function TCalculo.getSinal: char;
begin
  result := fsinal;
end;
```

Whenever I rum my program and press any button, I receive an error

> access violation at address 005FD704, read of address 0000000C:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Whole code:

https://github.com/murillojndem/Calculadora/blob/master/Unit1.pas

Comment: `TCalculo` is a *class* and in order to use it (except `class` variables, methods, and properties) you first need to create an instance (=object) of it. I bet you forgot that. (`calculo := TCalculo.Create` creates an object of this class and assigns a pointer to it to the `calculo` variable, which you then can use *after this line*. Before this line, `calculo` is either a `nil` pointer (if it is a global variable or a class member) or a "random garbage" pointer (if it is a local variable).)

Comment: A link to the code in an off-site location is not acceptable here. All relevant content needs to be here, in the question itself, in the form of a [mre]. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Where should I add the "calculo := TCalculo.create" though? Anywhere I try to add seems to return me errors.

Comment: You need to create the object *before* you use it. You then need to free it *after* you are done using it. This is the general truth. Remy gave you two very explicit examples in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

An Access Violation error near address `$00000000` usually means you are accessing memory via a `nil` pointer.

In this case, address `$0000000C` is 12 bytes from address `$00000000`.  The `TCalculo.getSinal()` method is accessing the `fsinal` member, which is at an offset of 12 bytes from the start of the `TCalculo` class (offset 0 is a hidden pointer to `TCalculo`'s vtable, offset 4 is the `fnumero1` member, offset 8 is the `fnumero2` member, and finally offset 12 is the `fsinal` member).

`result := fsinal;` is the same as `result := Self.fsinal;`, where the compiler adds the offset of `fsinal` (12) to the address that `Self` is pointing at, and then dereferences the resulting address to access the value of `fsinal`.  In your case, you are calling `TCalculo.getSinal()` via a `nil` pointer to a `TCalculo` object, so the method's `Self` pointer is `nil` (0), thus dereferencing the address of `fsinal` (0+12) causes an AV error.

In your `TForm` code, all of your `TButton.OnClick` handlers are calling `getSinal()` on a global `calculo` variable that is never being initialized to point at a valid `TCalculo` object.  Since the `calculo` variable is declared in global memory, it is default-initialized to `nil` at program startup.

```
type
  TCalculo = class(TObject)
    ...
  end;

var
  Form1  : TForm1;
  calculo: TCalculo; // <-- initialized to nil here!

...

procedure TForm1.Button0Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if calculo.getSinal = 'a' then // <-- calculo is still nil here!
  ...
end;

... and so on...
```

You need to add a call to `TCalculo.Create()`, either in the `TForm.OnCreate` event (and conversely, `Free` the object in the `TForm.OnDestroy` event), eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  calculo := TCalculo.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  calculo.Free;
end;
```

Or, use the unit's `initialization` section instead (and conversely, the `finalization` section), eg:

```
implementation

...

initialization
  calculo := TCalculo.Create;
finalization
  calculo.Free;

end.
```

Comment: Thenks for the detailed response, really appreciate it. But I did the same thing here and got no problem, why?

https://github.com/murillojndem/Calculadora-de-notas-N2-OOP-/blob/master/Unit1.pas

Comment: @MurilloJorge: No, you clearly have `calculo := TCalcula.create;` on line 48.

Comment: Which is a memory leak.  After the 1st click of `Button1`, the `calculo` object is never being `Free`'d. And each subsequent click is creating a *new* `TCalcula` object without `Free`'ing the previous object.